# Classic asp do while loop with time

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Is there possible to use Active Server Page to do a do while loop with time countdown to send email?

```
startTime   = dateAdd ("n",1,Now())
CurrentTime = Now()
 do
   CurrentTime = Now()
 loop while ( CDate(CurrentTime) < CDate(startTime)) = "True"

 //Send email code goes here
```

When I run this asp file on my website, its show me

```
An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
```

Answer (score 1):

ASP Classic (as any other server side scripting language) is not very suitable for timed actions like you are trying to do.

The script is called by e.g. a browser and only has limited time to fulfill a task before a timeout on client or server will terminate the running script. Also, the polling loop you have here can max out the CPU which can lead IIS to terminate the blocking script.

You could look for a solution that works as a program called regularly by the windows scheduler, a cron job or something alike.

Comment: will Java able to do the job?

Comment: @hiboss There's plenty of languages that could, just Classic ASP isn't one of them.